# Angular 2 keep input form value in bind with the model using getter and setter

Tags: angularjs, angular, data-binding, getter-setter

I would like to bind an input value to the model using getter and setters. In this way i can prevent and/or manipulate the input's value while writing inside it.

For example i want the prevent numbers inside an input box. So, if write 'abc' all is ok, then if I start writing a number nothing should happen (to the model and to the input's value). The issue is that with the following code i'm able to write anything inside the input box (but the model it's correct). This means that the input box value is not really representing my model.

NOTE: The reason beyond this questions is that I want to use my models to validate forms, preventing for example specific characters. I would like to not use reactive forms as **i want to keep my validations inside my models not components.** Also note that in a real scenario i would have a UserModel class with inside name and other fields with their validations.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2><input type="text" [(ngModel)]="name"> {{name}}</h2>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  _name:string = 'ss';
  constructor() {
  }

  // In real scenario those 2 methods are in a separate class UserModel
  get name() {
    return this._name;
  }

  set name() {
    if ((new RegExp(/^[a-zA-Z]*$/).test(val))) {
        this._name = val;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: I updated the question hope this is more clear now.

Comment: Please provide a concrete example about what you want. What you don't want isn't too helpful ;-) So if  `this._name` holds value `abc` and the user enters `123` but you don't want to allow numbers, what exactly should happen?

Comment: nothing, the input value should keep abc. (i'm adding a better example in the question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @Günter Zöchbauer answer i made a workaround. It's not definitive and could be more abstract, but for now it's ok.

```
export class App implements OnInit {
    @Input() userModel: UserModel = null;
    public _vm;

    constructor(private _changeDetectionRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    }

    /**
     * Initalize view model, it's important to keep names specular
     */
    ngOnInit() {
        this._vm = {
            name: this.userModel.name,
            surname: this.userModel.surname,
        };
    }

    /**
     * Helper for avoid detectchanges inside the modal, and reduce boilerplate. We could also ad an interface/type of the possibile field value, ie type fieldT= 'name' | 'surname';
     * @param field
     * @param val
     */
    protected updateModel(field, val: string): void {
        this._vm[field] = null;
        this._changeDetectionRef.detectChanges();
        this.userModel[field] = val;
        this._vm[field] = this.userModel[field];
        this._changeDetectionRef.detectChanges();
    }
}
```

In userModel:

```
....

    public get name(): string {
        return this.name';
    }

    public set name(val: string) {
        if ((new RegExp(/^[a-zA-Z]*$/).test(val))) {
            this.name = val;
        }
    }
```

In template:

```
<input type="text"  name="userName"  [ngModel]="_vm.name" (ngModelChange)="updateModel('name', $event)">
```

Answer (score 4):

If you manipulate the value in the setter, this can cause issues with change detection, so that `ngModel` doesn't pick up the changes and doesn't update the `<input>`

To work around you can use

```
export class App {

  _name:string = 'ss';

  constructor(private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  get name() {
    return this._name;
  }

  set name(value:String) {
    this._name = value + 'x';
    this.cdRef.detectChanges()
  }
}
```

if you reset the value to the previous value, you might need to pass an artificial different value first, otherwise change detection won't detect a change and even `detectChanges()` won't update the input.

```
  set name(value:String) {
    var oldVal = this._name;
    this._name = null;
    this.cdRef.detectChanges()
    this._name = oldVal;
    this.cdRef.detectChanges()
  }
```

Comment: This works but it's really tricky. I would like to not have detectChanges in all my model

Comment: I don't know of a better way.

Comment: from my testing, it's imperative to change the value first as described above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `(ngModelChange)` and `[ngModel]` to test the content of your model upon change.

As you can see in this **[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/spFOEczcmopYaAf51cBb?p=preview)** the model wont change if it is not valid.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2><input #input type="text" [ngModel]="name" (ngModelChange)='valid(input.value)'> {{name}}</h2>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string = 'ss';
  constructor() {
  }

  valid(value){
    if(value){ //<--- Your test here
      this.name = value;
    }
  }

}
```